# DOM Selectors in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a form with 5 `input[type='text']` in which only one has the attribute `class="dontSelectMe"`, how do I to select all these inputs without selecting `class="dontSelectMe"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pseudo Selectors:

```
input[type='text']:not(.dontSelectMe)
```

Comment: Isn't type of selector exclusive to jQuery?

Comment: @rm-vanda it is, though one would assume that's OK given that was one of the tags.

Comment: Of course. I'm fairly sure those tags were recently added, but it is worth mentioning anyway.

Comment: @rm-vanda - It isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through all the `input[type='text']`'s and check that their `className` isn't `dontSelectMe`, or use `:not`